# SSO for Microsoft Graph Call to UWP for Sharepoint Online Returns No Token

Tags: c#, uwp, single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-api

So I have been working on this UWP App for work.  I ran a test program on my developer site and got it to work perfectly.  I recreated the UWP App to access it on my company's platform and I am hitting a snag.  When I try to submit the data I get an MsalUIRequiredException error.

```
{Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: Null user was passed in AcquiretokenSilent API. Pass in a user object or call acquireToken authenticate.
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.SilentRequest..ctor(AuthenticationRequestParameters authenticationRequestParameters, Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientApplicationBase.<AcquireTokenSilentCommonAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientApplicationBase.<AcquireTokenSilentAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AshburnGeneratorApp.Authentication.<AquireTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: user_null
    StatusCode: 0
    Claims: }
```

I can see that it is telling me to use a tenant-specific endpoint or /organizations, which I thought I was.  So that is where I get confused.

```
{Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS90130: Application '87f68831-d1ea-493c-8b94-e61fcd1c4a08' (AshburnGeneratorApp) is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.
Trace ID: 888ba8ca-400f-43f9-8267-290c8e748100
Correlation ID: 121ef843-ef32-4126-aea8-0e17322df657
Timestamp: 2018-08-21 11:06:35Z
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.VerifyAuthorizationResult()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<PreTokenRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication.<AcquireTokenForLoginHintCommonAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AshburnGeneratorApp.Authentication.<AquireTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: invalid_request
    StatusCode: 0
    Claims: }
```

The PUT is going to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/companyname.sharepoint.com,495435b4-60c3-49b7-8f6e-1d262a120ae5,0fad9f67-35a8-4c0b-892e-113084058c0a/lists/18a725ac-83ef-48fb-a5cb-950ca2378fd0/items
```

where "companyname" is my actual company name.

If I run a GET on the Graph Explorer, the link works great.  So I know I am missing something simple somewhere.

The following code kicks off the authentication:

```
private async void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var (authResult, message) = await Authentication.AquireTokenAsync();
            ResultText.Text = message;

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                await SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(submiturl, authResult.AccessToken);
            }
        }
```

Which will call this code:

```
public static async Task<(AuthenticationResult authResult, string message)> AquireTokenAsync()
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            string message = String.Empty;
            string[] scopes = App.scopes;

            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    message = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
            }
            return (authResult, message);
        }
```

Scopes set

```
public static string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.ReadWrite", "Sites.ReadWrite.All" };
```

and last bit of code

```
private static string ClientId = "87f68831-d1ea-493c-8b94-e61fcd1c4a08";

public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get; } = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId);
```

Comment: Do you get an access token successfully? Could you try to create a simple sample to help me see your issue in my side? Note that please pay attention to your privacy in your code sample. You can also refer the [Microsoft Graph Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit//tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/Microsoft%20Graph%20Service) code.

Comment: @Breeze I see that even though it did work on another instance in my development, it is not working right in this one.  I am looking into the coding to figure it out.  I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was something simple.  I had not registered the app for v2.0.  Once I did that, everything worked great.